# I'm getting Wrong Version While Sending a SOAP Request

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a flight booking API. I'm sending the data to the server in following way:

```
        $location_URL = "http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightBooking?wsdl";
        $action_URL ="http://booking.flight.arzoo.com";

        $client = new SoapClient('http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightBooking?wsdl', array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'location' => $location_URL,
        'uri'      => $action_URL,
        'style'    => SOAP_RPC,
        'use'      => SOAP_ENCODED,
        'trace'    => 1,
        ));
```

I've also mentioned XML SOAP Body below edited parsed XML Formatted Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bookingrequest>
<onwardFlights>
<OriginDestinationOption>
<FareDetails>
<ChargeableFares>
<ActualBaseFare>5060</ActualBaseFare>
<Tax>4380</Tax>
<STax>32</STax>
<SCharge>0</SCharge>
<TDiscount>0</TDiscount>
<TPartnerCommission>0</TPartnerCommission>
</ChargeableFares>
<NonchargeableFares>
<TCharge>0</TCharge>
<TMarkup>300</TMarkup>
<TSdiscount>0</TSdiscount>
</NonchargeableFares>
</FareDetails>
<FlightSegments>
<FlightSegment>
<AirEquipType>321</AirEquipType>
<ArrivalAirportCode>DEL</ArrivalAirportCode>
<ArrivalDateTime>2013-10-20T08:00:00</ArrivalDateTime>
<DepartureAirportCode>BOM</DepartureAirportCode>
<DepartureDateTime>2013-10-20T06:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
<FlightNumber>6019</FlightNumber>
<OperatingAirlineCode>AI</OperatingAirlineCode>
<OperatingAirlineFlightNumber>6019</OperatingAirlineFlightNumber>
<RPH>
</RPH>
<StopQuantity>0</StopQuantity>
<airLineName>Air India</airLineName>
<airportTax>4380</airportTax>
<imageFileName>http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif</imageFileName>
<viaFlight>
</viaFlight>
<BookingClass>
<Availability>4</Availability>
<ResBookDesigCode>U</ResBookDesigCode>
</BookingClass>
<BookingClassFare>
<adultFare>5060</adultFare>
<bookingclass>U</bookingclass>
<classType>Economy</classType>
<farebasiscode>fjyS3YyUlEusLfJ4bwgPvQ==</farebasiscode>
<Rule>This fare is Refundable &lt;br&gt; Baggage : 25K&lt;br&gt;Booking Class : U|Re-Schedule Charges: Rs. 750 per sector + Fare difference (If any) +admin fee 500 + Service Fee of Rs. 250 &#13;
Sector .|Cancellation Charges : Basic fare +Airline administration fee 500  + Service Charges 250 Per Passenger Per Sector .&#13;
                        |</Rule>
<adultCommission>0</adultCommission>
<childCommission>0</childCommission>
<commissionOnTCharge>0</commissionOnTCharge>
</BookingClassFare>
<Discount>0</Discount>
<airportTaxChild>0</airportTaxChild>
<airportTaxInfant>0</airportTaxInfant>
<adultTaxBreakup>2950,147,1283</adultTaxBreakup>
<childTaxBreakup>0,0,0</childTaxBreakup>
<infantTaxBreakup>0,0,0</infantTaxBreakup>
<octax>0</octax>
</FlightSegment>
</FlightSegments>
<id>arzoo11</id>
<key>wtZcSVMY/gphWFSOTFWg8nkII1434EZIGjnpJNQzayEK8sDjVS91GicTJzH+TWN+pNURIyTJYKOW&#13;
O8yH8+0tzpA4t8aEEvzaOE6ZnTtBotFDwLtSiN0xXiTOGgS0siJI1l7d9ata/3rxTgfh9d8ZSmFY&#13;
VI5MVaDyd5WrIWHlQL5zqWDbQb1E1IoDSY1wep73c6lg20G9RNQQnpVlWM7U0ZY7zIfz7S3O4J6m&#13;
G25LJItzqWDbQb1E1IoDSY1wep73c6lg20G9RNSKA0mNcHqe93OpYNtBvUTUpvdITjbFOR52+H1V&#13;
tJqs5kJfo6Sh44vDThgZv6ARhgviIKxphH+kbb9fDhZYRaCPm3lupCgitSmWO8yH8+0tzolfF9kG&#13;
WM+AaZ58PxEZgqCbbbGbXj1Z0D7dHS59eVX1JxMnMf5NY37ZbJ5llqmBpycTJzH+TWN+2WyeZZap&#13;
gacnEycx/k1jftlsnmWWqYGnJxMnMf5NY37ZbJ5llqmBpycTJzH+TWN+2WyeZZapgacnEycx/k1j&#13;
ftlsnmWWqYGnJxMnMf5NY36po4tljIBmEJgePqv2qP9fd/Usd8Uuz7FDwLtSiN0xXvtUK9az69O/&#13;
JxMnMf5NY37yK2PFSCI6AM2hLlYrFkYJQ8C7UojdMV7NoS5WKxZGCcr5VjCR04wgRviI6n9DzL3N&#13;
oS5WKxZGCUPAu1KI3TFezaEuVisWRglDwLtSiN0xXv4Xbn4sigRMv18OFlhFoI/cKcKe7FftvScT&#13;
JzH+TWN+2WyeZZapgacnEycx/k1jftlsnmWWqYGnJxMnMf5NY377Oxb/b44TR5Y7zIfz7S3O16CE&#13;
sDaAROm13h/OHWeGHw==</key>
</OriginDestinationOption>
</onwardFlights>
<returnFlights>
</returnFlights>
<personName>
<CustomerInfo>
<givenName>Rajnish</givenName>
<surName>Dubey</surName>
<nameReference>Mr.</nameReference>
<psgrtype>adt</psgrtype>
</CustomerInfo>
</personName>
<telePhone>
<phoneNumber>9595959595</phoneNumber>
</telePhone>
<email>
<emailAddress>rajnishdubey1988@gmail.com</emailAddress>
</email>
<creditcardno>5266474530046446</creditcardno>
<Clientid>7232326</Clientid>
<Clientpassword>*AB424E52FBBHDSFS74DFFSA7B747A9BAF61F8E</Clientpassword>
<partnerRefId>100200</partnerRefId>
<Clienttype>ArzooFWS1.1</Clienttype>
<AdultPax>1</AdultPax>
<ChildPax>0</ChildPax>
<InfantPax>0</InfantPax>
</Bookingrequest>

        try
    {
        //$result = $client->getAvailability($dom->saveXML($request));
        $result = $client->getBookingDetails($dom->saveXML($request));
        $response= htmlentities($result);
        echo "<h1> Client Response: </h1><pre>".htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_QUOTES)."</pre>";

    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>";
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Now when the data is being sent to the server I get an exception 'Wrong version'. I checked on the SERVER side, the log for this particular client isn't being hit at all. Means that the server didn't received the request. The same WSDL request format is created by AVAILABILITY API of the flight. I'm getting the available flight list by AVAILABILITY API. I converted the above code in XML, the API documentation has the same format as i'm sending the request. I checked on the internet but didn't find the solution for the same. Some says the version of SOAP i'm using is different but that's not the case. Because the Flight and Hotel Availability API Has same method of request and receiving the data from server. 
Please help me. I'm stuck on this. Your help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you've got a WSDL and a Soap Client, why do you create the XML by hand? Just for the fun?

Comment: Hahahaaa.. No.. Not exactly. Passing the string in XML tags used to create the problem while sending an SOAP Request with an operation name declaration. That's the reason actually. If you have any better solution please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: To which kind of Operation Name Declaration do you rely to? Please provide reference to the SOAP standard specification documents so I can suggest you something.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply. I've added the actual XML formatted request which is to be sent to the server in the code. Please have a look at it. The operation name is 'getBookingDetails' for booking details. The above XML request is in the same format as given in API Document. I asked the API Provider but they say there is no error in API Document as with same document reference others are getting the response. Any suggestions?

Comment: You actually make me repeat myself. See my first comment. You're just doing it for the fun, right? Creating XML by hand despite there's a WSDL? And then push the "Any suggestions?" rhetorical afterwards for not saying you're gussing around with something you don't have the earth under your feets? Get the rubber on the road first and learn the tools you use. And check the code-example you've posted it looks wrong-formatted, incomplete and by far not self-contained. Please post examples that can be easily executed to reproduce the issue you describe in your question - by anyone.

Comment: Let me add to your comment.. I tried nusoap wsdl component for php but that didn't helped me. It was giving me the error as invalid format and operation name, i was in hurry to complete the availability part that's why i chosed this format to send the request. And so i used the sme working format in booking also. If you've SOAP WSDL working format then please share. I shall use that, probably this could help me with the problem

Comment: I know that PHP's SoapClient does work with WSDLs, it is normally only a problem for users (and I include myself in that group) to get started with it. I never fell back to NuSoap as I think it's not the time any longer that it is needed because there is SoapClient. And I did use SoapClient successfully, try to better binpoint what exactly is your originating problem with using it and that specific webservices, let's come to a solution step-by-step, that works normally fastest.

Comment: So far your code works, there is no such error: http://codepad.viper-7.com/q2eHCB - Please add as little code as necessary to turn that example into one demonstrating the *original* problem.

Comment: I tried on codeviper as well. but got wrong version in the output. I simply paste my code and replaced variable's value as received by the availability API. Still facing this error..

Answer (score 0):

this is working code of flight availibility by arzoo..
i also getting error while using SOAP CLIENT but when i use nusoap then they give me result..using this code if u get error like ip/password mismatch then You will call arzoo to verify your clientid and clientpassword

```
    <?php
  ini_set('max_execution_time','180');
    include 'lib/nusoap.php';
   $location_URL ='http://avail.flight.arzoo.com';
   $action_URL ='http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl';
$Request = '<Request>
<Origin>BOM</Origin>
<Destination>DEL</Destination>
<DepartDate>2017-02-02</DepartDate>
<ReturnDate>2017-02-02</ReturnDate>
<AdultPax>1</AdultPax>
<ChildPax>0</ChildPax>
<InfantPax>0</InfantPax>
<Currency>INR</Currency>
<Clientid>Given by Arzoo.com</Clientid>
<Clientpassword>Given by Arzoo.com</Clientpassword>
<Clienttype>ArzooFWS1.1</Clienttype>
<Preferredclass>E</Preferredclass>
<mode>ONE</mode>
<PreferredAirline>AI</PreferredAirline>
</Request>';

$clientinfo = array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
'location' =>$location_URL,
'uri' =>$action_URL,
 'style' => SOAP_RPC,
 'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
 'trace' => 1,
 );

 $client = new nusoap_client('http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl', $clientinfo);
//print_r($client);
$result = $client->call('getAvailability', array($Request));
echo"<pre>";
print_r($result);
$clientInfo =simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($result));
$flight = $clientInfo->Response__Depart->OriginDestinationOptions->OriginDestinationOption;
$error =$clientInfo->error__tag;
//echo $error;
var_dump($flight);
//exit;
//echo"<pre>";
//print_r($result);
//ECHO $error;
?>
```